# move image on each click Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to move an image on each click but using this code works only on one click.

```js
function moveright() {
  console.log("moveright invoked.");
  var myImg = document.getElementById("image");
  myImg.style.position = "absolute";
  var cLeft = myImg.style.left;
  if (cLeft == 500) {
    console("Maximum reached.");
  } else {
    myImg.style.left = (cLeft + 50) + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiYE3.jpg?s=32&g=1" onclick="moveright()" />
```

Comment: I have added snippet for you. See the function is getting invoked.

Comment: Please do `console.log(cLeft + 50);` to see what you get. It is not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 4):

1. Give an initial left position value. You can add an inline style like this: `style="left: 0px"`
2. Parse the left value to an integer before adding 50 px to it: `var cLeft = parseInt(myImg.style.left);`

```js
function moveright() {
  var myImg = document.getElementById("image");
  myImg.style.position = "absolute";
  var cLeft = parseInt(myImg.style.left);
  
  if (cLeft == 500) {
    console("Maximum reached.");
  } else {
    myImg.style.left = (cLeft + 50) + "px";
  }  
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiYE3.jpg?s=32&g=1" onclick="moveright()"  style="left: 0px" />
```

Alternatively, you can skip the `left` style declaration and get the computed style value using `window.getComputedStyle`.

```js
function moveright() {
  var myImg = document.getElementById("image");
  myImg.style.position = "absolute";
  
  var cLeft = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(myImg).left);
  
  if (cLeft == 500) {
    console("Maximum reached.");
  } else {
    myImg.style.left = (cLeft + 50) + "px";
  }  
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiYE3.jpg?s=32&g=1" onclick="moveright()" />
```

Comment: `Thoppil`: In general When using `getComputedStyle` please ensure to read the [**getComputedStyle Notes Section**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Notes) to be aware of it's possibly different results. Specifically `The returned value is, in certain known cases, expressly inaccurate by deliberate intent.` - This is a general comment to ensure OP is aware of it before potentially using it beyond the scope of this question and not reflecting anything in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `parseInt`, as `style.left` has value in px. If `style.left` is empty, pass 0 as initial value.

```js
function moveright() {
  var myImg = document.getElementById("image");
  myImg.style.position = "absolute";
  var cLeft = parseInt(myImg.style.left || 0);

  if (cLeft == 500) {
    alert("Maximum reached.");
  } else {
    myImg.style.left = (cLeft + 50) + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiYE3.jpg?s=32&g=1" onclick="moveright()" />
```